# Does a power of endomorphism factor through a projective?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, radicals, projective-module

Let $A$ be a ring (e.g. an $R$-algebra over a noetherian local ring $R$), $M$ an indecomposable $A$-module, and $f$ an endomorphism, which is not an isomorphism.
Now, we assume that the endomorphism ring of $M$ is a local ring.

Then, does a power of $f$ factor through a projective $A$-module?

If $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field, then this is true by the Harada-Sai lemma.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In full generality, the answer is no.  Take $A = K[[x,y]]$, the ring of power series in variables $x$ and $y$ with coefficient in a field $K$.  Take $M = K[[x,y]]/\langle y \rangle$.  Then the endomorphism ring of $M$ is isomorphic to a ring of formal power series $K[[\phi]]$, where an endomorphism $p(\phi) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i \phi^i$ applied to a $z\in M$ is defined by
$$
 p(\phi)(z) := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i xz.
$$
Finally, take $f=\phi$.  Then $f$ is not an isomorphism, and no power of $f$ vanishes.  However, there are no non-zero morphisms from $M$ to $A$ (and thus to any projective module).  So $f$ does not factor through a projective module.

---

If, moreover, the endormosphism ring of $M$ is Artinian (which happens if $A$ is an algebra over a field and $M$ is of finite length over $A$, for instance), then any non-invertible endomorphism of $M$ is nilpotent.  Thus a power of $f$ vanishes, and trivially factors through a projective module.